# Freeradius radacct table is empty

Tags: accounting, freeradius2

I am using Freeradius 2 in FreeBSD server.

The server is able to authenticate the user in MySQL database but i found that radacct table is not updated. I have check the configuration in the /sites-enable/default. sql has been uncomment in accounting{}. In /sql/mysql/dialup.conf, postauth query is able to run and insert info indatabase when user log in to the system but accounting start query is not working in the same.

Please help me as i really don have any idea on how to fix it . Thank you.

Comment: Have you verified your NAS is actually sending accounting packets? Use ``radsniff -x -i <interface>`` to check. You should see Accounting-Request packets right after the server sends an Access-Accept.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell May i ask what kind of interface should i check at this case?

Comment: The network interface that is associated with the ip you're sending RADIUS packets to.